# can not setup or update anything after a mistaken command

Tags: apt

I was trying to setup mongodb for my class work and as there setup tutorial is followed this command:

```
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list
```

After this I can't setup anything, I can't even use `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First thing first:**

Press  *CRTL+ALT+T*  to open terminal.

**Second thing:**

Copy and paste `gksudo nautilus /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` into the terminal and press ENTER.

**Finally:**

Look for '10gen.list'   and delete it from the source list. Save it and exit. Next thing is to type `sudo apt-get update` at the terminal to update your files.

Comment: It doesn't found. No line matches with that line..

full error is

nihan@Heelbook:/etc$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for nihan: 
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: Okay. copy and paste   gksudo nautilus /etc/apt/sources.list.d   and look for   10gen.lis   and delete it. I think that will solve the problem.

Comment: @all4naija could you please, write in your answer just to delete `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list`

Comment: @ Braiam. Okay, I would do just that right away. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

Another method using the very same terminal is:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list
sudo apt-get update
```

With this you prevent damaging your system due having the nautilus using the root user.